# Memory Error occurs while working with large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, error-handling, out-of-memory

I have the interpolated data of 3 numpy arrays.

```
Each of Length - 107952899
```

## Problem Facing

When i combine these three numpy array as pandas df, I am getting `MemoryError`.

## Reason for converting to df

I have to do some calculations, pandas make it more easier, so i preferred doing with pandas.
I believe that memory size of three numpy array crosses 3 Gb and more.

## System Details:

8Gb RAM
python 3.6.3

## Requirement

I understand the reason for such a Error
But Is there any possibility to avoid MemoryError, or some other best practice to be followed ??

Comment: If not all your data is required at once for the calculation have you considered splitting it in smaller chunks and than put the results back together?  For example if you want to sum all elements in an array, you don't need all the array at once, you can calculate the sum of the chunks and than sum this results to obtain the final value

Comment: You may think about downcasting your data to `np.float32` or even `np.float16`.

Comment: Could you provide your code? Or a simplified example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 2):

> When i combine these three numpy array as pandas df, I am getting MemoryError.

Let's say that you do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

big_array_1 = np.array(np.random.random(10**7))
big_array_2 = np.array(np.random.random(10**7))
big_array_3 = np.array(np.random.random(10**7))
```

On my computer, it takes around 300 MB of memory.

Then if I do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([big_array_1,big_array_2, big_array_3])
```

The memory soars up to 9Gb of ram. If you multiply it by a factor 10 (to get your 3 Gb of data instead of my 300), you will go up to 90 Gb which is probably more then your Ram + available swap, which would raise a `MemoryError`.

But if instead, you do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":big_array_1, "B": big_array_2, "C":big_array_3})
```

then your usage of memory will not be significantly bigger than the one of your three arrays.

I suspect that it is your issue...

Comment: Well, you should answer to my question on what code you are using (or a code that replicates your issue, you may use my example...). Moreover, you should give more information about your system: Linux, Windows, MacOS. The problem is either in your code, or due to your system (e.g., no swap file on Linux, very small Pagefile.sys max size on windows, or not full HDD/SSD on MacOS). It's hard to help without more pieces of information.